# Stochastic hline cross on different timeframe

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to create a strategy where i look at the hourly timeframe for signals (stochastic D line above 60 or below 40 hline) , then to execute the trade on the 15 minute timeframs- but i am not having much success with the hline expression in the security function. Can someone please advise of a better or different way to do this.

Here is the code to define the stochastic properties on the hourly timeframe, whilst the chart is being focused on the 15 minute timeframe

I am getting the following error message: Type hline cannot be used in security "expression" argument

***////PINE SCRIPT***

```
htf_stoch_k = security(syminfo.tickerid,"60",sma(stoch(close, high, low, 14), 1),lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
htf_stoch_d = security(syminfo.tickerid,"60",sma(htf_stoch_k, 3),lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
htf_stoch_h0 = security(syminfo.tickerid,"60",hline(60, "Upper Band", color=#787B86),lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
htf_stoch_h1 = security(syminfo.tickerid,"60",hline(40, "Lower Band", color=#787B86),lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go buddy (this has no repaint),

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © SafetyHammer

//@version=4
study("My Script")
Length = input(14, minval=1, title="Stochastic Length")
smoothK = input(1, title="Smoothing of Stochastic K")
smoothD = input(3, title="Smoothing of Stochastic D")

Res_stoch_k     = input(title="Stoch K Resolution", type=input.resolution, defval="60")  
Res_stoch_d     = input(title="Stoch D Resolution", type=input.resolution, defval="60")  

f_secureSecurity(_symbol, _res, _src) => security(_symbol, _res, _src[1],barmerge.gaps_on, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on) // orignal code line


Sto             = stoch(close, high, low, Length)
K               = sma(Sto, smoothK)
D               = sma(Sto, smoothD)


htf_stoch_k     = f_secureSecurity(syminfo.tickerid, Res_stoch_k, K)
htf_stoch_d     = f_secureSecurity(syminfo.tickerid, Res_stoch_d, D)


upper_bound     = input(title="Upper Bound", type=input.integer, defval=60, minval=0, maxval=100)  // User input for overbought horizontal line
lower_bound     = input(title="Lower Bound", type=input.integer, defval=40, minval=0, maxval=100)  // User input for oversold horizontal line

upper_hl        = hline(upper_bound, title="Upper bound") 
lower_hl        = hline(lower_bound, title="Lower bound")

top_hl          = hline(100, title="100 bound") 
bottom_hl       = hline(0, title="0 bound")

fill(top_hl, upper_hl, color=color.new(color.red,80))
fill(lower_hl, bottom_hl, color=color.new(color.blue,80))

plot(htf_stoch_k, title="htf_stoch K", color=color.new(color.blue,10))
plot(htf_stoch_d, title="htf stoch D", color=color.new(color.red,10))
```